# How to use ASP.NET Core Identity UI with custom Authentication service instead Services.AddDefaultIdentity

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.dll (net6.0) contains a series of useful pages

[image]

but any example uses default identity, something like that

```
 Builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity(Of IdentityUser)(Sub(options) options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = True).AddEntityFrameworkStores(Of ApplicationDbContext)
```

This Identity based on IdentityUser (expanded from ApplicationUser) and EF memory buffers related to DB.

This way is not applicable to my project. I have Scoped service what can notify me - is password correct or not, what roles has current user and so on.

Can I use this Identity pages with my service UserService? Without definition of IdentityUser and EF (Of IdentityUser).
How I can initialize services in DI container for use IdentityUI and than simple use

```
    App.UseAuthentication()
    App.UseAuthorization()
```

Or IdentityUI don't applicable to custom user identification service at all?
And can I use UseAuthentication/UseAuthorization with my custom user identification service?

Comment: i would like to do the same exact thing.... i'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: @FuMe, I have solved this problem, I will publish solution to Github during weekend and place link there.

Comment: great! i didn't even give it a try, so i would really appreciate to see how youy solved the thing!

Comment: @FuMe  If u still have interesting, please look to my solution https://github.com/Alex-1557/CustomIdentityInsteadDefaultIdentity